# Issue with bootstrap sprockets in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, localhost, sprockets

As said in the title, I get an error message when I try to access my localhost:3000.

The message is :

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Welcome#index

Showing /home/dameaw/work/five/meawinit/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/dameaw/work/five/meawinit/app/assets/config
  /home/dameaw/work/five/meawinit/app/assets/images
  /home/dameaw/work/five/meawinit/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/dameaw/work/five/meawinit/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/toastr-rails-1.0.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/toastr-rails-1.0.3/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2/vendor/assets/images
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.7/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.1.7/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/dameaw/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
```

I try to get rid of '//= require bootstrap-sprockets' in the application.js file but when I do that, the style is completly broken.

Thank you for your advices in advances and have a sweet day :)

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4, then did you carefully follow this guide - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails ? You'll also need to add `jquery` as it says in guide. If you're using Bootstrap 3 then did you follow this carefully - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails?